# regex: verify root path in subpath

Tags: regex

I have the following subpath: /root_folder/folder1/folder2/

How do I use a regex to verify that /root_folder/ is the first part of the above string (sql similar to).

Comment: You can probably use simple string operations provided by the language you are using. E.g. in JavaScript, you'd check whether `indexOf` returns `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This must be the simplest regex ever:

```
'~^/root_folder/~'
```

You don't have to use `~`. You can use any other delimiter, just be sure to escape it in the regex...